# How to plot the overlapping area of figures in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, overlap, figure

I want to plot the overlapping area of 2 rectangles in a color. I know I can plot the rectangles by using the rectangle command. With rectint I can find out whether they overlap or not.

Is there a specific command for this or does anyone know how I can do this? As you have noticed, I do not have much experience with Matlab.

Code:

```
     A = [0 0 3 3];
     B = [2 2 2 2];

     hold on;
     rectangle('Position',A) %plot rectangle A
     rectangle('Position',B) %plot rectangle B
     if (rectint(A,B) > 0)
          %plot overlapping
     end
     hold off;
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: wouldn't be half-transparent rectangles also a good solution?

Comment: Since I will use this for building a localization map I rather have a square represent the belief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rectangles overlap, the part for the plotting could be done like this:

```
    if (A(1)<=B(1))
        intersection(1)=B(1);
        intersection(3)=A(1)+A(3)-B(1);
    else
        intersection(1)=A(1);
        intersection(3)=B(1)+B(3)-A(1);
    end

    if (A(2)<=B(2))
        intersection(2)=B(2);
        intersection(4)=A(2)+A(4)-B(2);
    else
        intersection(2)=A(2);
        intersection(4)=B(2)+B(4)-A(2);
    end

    intersectionPlot=rectangle('Position', intersection);
    set(intersectionPlot, 'FaceColor', 'r'); % r stands for red, you can choose any other color
```

Comment: Apparently as Dennis Jaheruddin stated, there is no function for this. This selfwritten code works perfect. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

So you only want to plot the little rectangle in the middle? 
I don't think that there is a builtin function for that, and this is probably the way to go:

1. Determine the coordinates of the intersection (as long as it are just rectangles this should not be too hard)
2. Plot the result

Comment: I noticed that there are a lot of functions in Matlab but just couldn't find this one. I think you are right when you say that there isn't a function for this. For those who want an example for rectangles the solution of nbanic works perfect!